# inner types in a module and creating a record

Tags: f#

I've a type defined inside a module and trying to create a record of that.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1

    module Data = 

        type Location = {Latitude: double; Longitude: double}
```

inside my test method

```
namespace TestProject2

open System
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
open ClassLibrary1
open Data

[<TestClass>]
type TestClass () =

    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.TestMethod3 () =
       let location = {Latitude=40.0; Longitude=40.1}
       // Console.WriteLine location
```

**Error**

> let and do bindings must come before member and interface definitions
>   in type definitions.

[image]

Comment: Did you `open Data` in your test module?

Comment: yes it's open, the namespace is open basically, I've another type defined at root level and it's accessible, the one nested inside Data is not

Comment: Hold on a second, are you saying that the `Data` module is nested inside some other module or namespace? And you're saying that the surrounding module or namespace is open? But is `Data` itself open?

Comment: i opened both the namespace and the Data, it's still saying let and do binding must come before.

Comment: Can you please post a minimal compete example? It's very hard to guess what exactly is going on in your code.

Comment: edited with some more context, the compiler suggests `open Data` is not required.

Comment: open ClassLibrary1.Data

Comment: sorry, same issue

Answer (score 0):

Least expected but turns out this is the way to define records from nested types, hopefully someone can shed light on this, find a better way etc.

```
let location = {Data.Latitude=40.0; Data.Longitude=40.1}
```

Comment: I have no trouble compiling the code shown in the original question. There must be more to this than what we can see in the posted code.

Comment: perhaps that I'm on a mac compiling using Rider.